# Round down a numeric

Tags: r, significant-digits

I have `numeric`'s like this one:

```
a <- -1.542045
```

And I want to round them down (or round up the `abs`) to 2 digits after the decimal point. 
`signif(a,3)` will round it down and give me 1.54 as a result but for this example the result I want is `-1.55`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you are looking for `floor(a * 100) / 100`.

**Quick Test**

```
a <- c(-1.542045, 1.542045)
floor(a * 100) / 100
# [1] -1.55  1.54
```

---

I just noticed that you changed your question 7 hours ago. Then my answer is not doing exactly what you want (as I am assuming by "rounding down" you always want to round toward `-Inf`). But I have discussed this in first version of my answer. Now I am going to copy those relevant back here.

- With `sign(a) * ceiling(abs(a) * 100) / 100` you can round data toward `Inf` for positive values and `-Inf` for negative values.
- With `sign(a) * floor(abs(a) * 100) / 100`, you round both positive and negative values toward 0.

**A quick test**

```
a <- c(-1.542045, 1.542045)

sign(a) * ceiling(abs(a) * 100) / 100
# [1] -1.55  1.55

sign(a) * floor(abs(a) * 100) / 100
# [1] -1.54  1.54
```

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the issue.  If the value is in -1.542045, it will always be.

Now you can *print* it to two decimals or get a two decimal char:

```
> print(a, digits=3)
[1] -1.54
> format(a, digits=3)
[1] "-1.54"
>
```

Should you *really* desire to create a new *representation* you can:

```
> b <- trunc(a*1e2)*1e-2
> b
[1] -1.54
>
```

A preferable way may be

```
> b <- round(a, digits=2)
> b
[1] -1.54
>
```

Answer (score 2):

A combination of `ceiling()`, `abs()` and `sign()` can be used to round up the abs of the number, irrespective of its sign. Such a rounding at two decimal digits can be obtained with:

```
ceiling(abs(a)*100)/100*sign(a)
```

Example:

```
a <- c(-1.542045, 1.542045)
ceiling(abs(a)*100)/100*sign(a)
#[1] -1.55  1.55
```